# pandas - transform data view

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

i have pandas data frame that looks like below, where id and date are the indices

```
id      name    date        gross1  gross2  net1    net2    balance1    balance2
1       abc     01/01/2001  100     101     50      51      200         201 
2       def     01/02/2001  201     202     40      41      300         3001
3       ghi     01/03/2001  300     303     99      98      1000        10001
```

I would like to transform this such that data is transformed like this:

```
id  date        level   parent  category    name    value1  value1
1   01/01/2001  0       NaN     gross       abc     100     101
2   01/01/2001  1       1       net         abc     50      51
3   01/01/2001  1       1       balance     abc     200     201

4   01/02/2001  0       NaN     gross       def     201     201
5   01/02/2001  1       4       net         def     40      41
6   01/02/2001  1       4       balance     def     300     3001

7   01/03/2001  0       NaN     gross       ghi     300     303
8   01/03/2001  1       7       net         ghi     99      98
9   01/03/2001  1       7       balance     ghi     1000    10001
```

i tried pivoting and unstacking...but couldn't quite get it right. Closes i came was doing something like below:

```
df_gross = df['name','gross1','gross2']
df_gross.columns = ['name', 'value1', 'value2']
df_gross['level']=0
df_gross['category']='gross'

df_net = df['name', 'net1','net2']
df_net.columns = ['name', 'value1', 'value2']
df_gross['level']=1
df_gross['category']='net'

df_balance = df['name', 'balance1','balance2']
df_balance.columns = ['name', 'value1', 'value2']
df_balance['level']=1
df_balance['category']='balance'
df = pandas.concat(df_gross, df_net, df_balance)
```

the issue i'm having however is how to efficiently generate a new id, and  set the parent column to the newly generated id.
I could..after the concat, reset_index, then drop the 'id' column then set the index to the pandas generated index (which should be values 1..n).  then i'm thinking i do a dataframe.apply to find parent by 'date' and 'level=0' and set parent accordingly.   Would that be the most efficient way?

Comment: Why is the first parent ID NaN?  Is this desired?

Comment: Yes..null..indicating top level.  could make it self i i suppose.

Comment: I just noticed the "credible and/or official sources" note.  Not sure what that means but everything in my answer is standard use of numpy/pandas.

Comment: does the `parent row` have to be the one with `category = gross`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I can think to do this involves reshaping the indices and names via pandas and reshaping the values with numpy.

First, let's reshape the numerical values in numpy:

```
arr = df.ix[:,'gross1':'balance2'].values.reshape(9,2)

array([[  100,   101],
       [   50,    51],
       [  200,   201],
       [  201,   202],
       [   40,    41],
       [  300,  3001],
       [  300,   303],
       [   99,    98],
       [ 1000, 10001]], dtype=int64)
```

Now let's reshape the dataframe in pandas so that indices and column names are closer to what we want:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['id','date','name']).stack().iloc[::2].reset_index().iloc[:,:-1]

   id        date name   level_3
0   1  01/01/2001  abc    gross1
1   1  01/01/2001  abc      net1
2   1  01/01/2001  abc  balance1
3   2  01/02/2001  def    gross1
4   2  01/02/2001  def      net1
5   2  01/02/2001  def  balance1
6   3  01/03/2001  ghi    gross1
7   3  01/03/2001  ghi      net1
8   3  01/03/2001  ghi  balance1
```

That's basically 90% of it, now just combine them:

```
df2[['value1','value2']] = pd.DataFrame(arr)

   id        date name   level_3  value1  value2
0   1  01/01/2001  abc    gross1     100     101
1   1  01/01/2001  abc      net1      50      51
2   1  01/01/2001  abc  balance1     200     201
3   2  01/02/2001  def    gross1     201     202
4   2  01/02/2001  def      net1      40      41
5   2  01/02/2001  def  balance1     300    3001
6   3  01/03/2001  ghi    gross1     300     303
7   3  01/03/2001  ghi      net1      99      98
8   3  01/03/2001  ghi  balance1    1000   10001
```

I'm not sure how you intend to use the level/parent colunns, but here's how you can set them up:

```
df2['parent'] = df2.groupby('id').cumcount()
df2['parent_index'] = df2[ df2.parent == 0 ].index.to_series()
df2['parent_index'] = df2.parent_index.fillna(method='ffill')
df2['parent'] = np.where( df2.parent > 1, 1, df2.parent )
df2['parent_index'] = np.where( df2.parent == 0, np.nan, df2.parent_index )

   id        date name   level_3  value1  value2  parent  parent_index
0   1  01/01/2001  abc    gross1     100     101       0           NaN
1   1  01/01/2001  abc      net1      50      51       1             0
2   1  01/01/2001  abc  balance1     200     201       1             0
3   2  01/02/2001  def    gross1     201     202       0           NaN
4   2  01/02/2001  def      net1      40      41       1             3
5   2  01/02/2001  def  balance1     300    3001       1             3
6   3  01/03/2001  ghi    gross1     300     303       0           NaN
7   3  01/03/2001  ghi      net1      99      98       1             6
8   3  01/03/2001  ghi  balance1    1000   10001       1             6
```

Comment: thanks..i'm curious how i would do this based on what i had accomplished thus far?  splitting the dataframe into 3 dataframes by selecting the relevant columns.  Given that, how could i generate the ids and parent ids in the manner i desire?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question but can say 2 things:  (1) usually it's better to keep related things in the same dataframe rather than split them out.  (2) You might want to post a new followup question showing exactly what you want to do with this data.  Sometime it's better to ask how to achieve some results while leaving the method in pandas somewhat open.

Comment: That said, you could peel off 'gross' in the original data set with something like ```df_gross = df[['id','date','name','gross1','gross2']]```  or ```df_gross = df2[ df2.level_3 == 'gross1']```.  ButI suspect you're going to be better off keeping things together and using ```groupby('id')``` for processing -- though again I don't know exactly what sorts of things you want to do here.

Comment: what's happening is the data comes in one huge table with 43 columns! The first 3 can be considered the key, and the following 40 columns can be broken out into 4 categories, 10 cols each that can be stacked on top of ea other (i.e. 10 cols shows data for world, 10 cols for North America, 10 cols for Europe and 10 columns for Asia).  what i want to do is display them like that in a tree view grid..where the 'world' data is the parent, if a user cases, they can expand to see the breakdown.

Comment: Well, you have options.  I would just post a new question if I were you, but you can either keep everything in the same dataset and use selection techniques or separate and then re-merge each time.  You might want to keep the parent data in **each row** which is duplicative but if your data is not that big is not really a problem and may simplify some things (so that you don't have to re-merge each time.  I'm speculating a bit which is why it's probably best to just do a followup question and show exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done completely in using pandas only.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# assuming your dataframe is called `df`, first stack the dataframe
dfnew = df.set_index(['id', 'date','name']).stack().reset_index()

# split the category information into category and value level, then delete column level_3
dfnew[['category', 'valuelevel']] = dfnew.level_3.apply(
        lambda x: pd.Series([x[:-1], x[-1]]))
del dfnew['level_3']

# reshape data to meet required format and reset_index
dfnew = dfnew.set_index(['id', 'date', 'name', 'category', 'valuelevel']).unstack(level=-1).reset_index()

# fix MultiIndex mess by flattening the column names, 
# note: renaming id to parent because that is what it will end up being, new id will be the index.
dfnew.columns = ['parent', 'date', 'name', 'category', 'value1', 'value2']

# reorder the data frame according to parent_id & category ['gross', 'net', 'balance'], 
# using a second data frame
# then get rid of the extra fields `index` & `catlevel`
cat_level = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['gross', 'net', 'balance'], 'catlevel': [0, 1, 2]})
dfnew = dfnew.merge(cat_level)
dfnew = dfnew.sort(['parent', 'catlevel']).reset_index()
del dfnew['index']
del dfnew['catlevel']

# generate the new row id from index
dfnew['id'] = dfnew.reset_index()['index'] + 1

# reset the parent column to point to the current parent id
dfnew['parent'] = dfnew.groupby('parent')['id'].transform(min)

# add new column level
dfnew['level'] = 1

# update the parent & level columns based on the mask parent == id
mask = dfnew.parent == dfnew.id
dfnew.level[mask] = 0
dfnew.parent[mask] = np.NaN
```

The final data frame looks like:

```
   parent        date name category  value1  value2  id  level
0     NaN  01/01/2001  abc    gross     100     101   1      0
1       1  01/01/2001  abc      net      50      51   2      1
2       1  01/01/2001  abc  balance     200     201   3      1
3     NaN  01/02/2001  def    gross     201     202   4      0
4       4  01/02/2001  def      net      40      41   5      1
5       4  01/02/2001  def  balance     300    3001   6      1
6     NaN  01/03/2001  ghi    gross     300     303   7      0
7       7  01/03/2001  ghi      net      99      98   8      1
8       7  01/03/2001  ghi  balance    1000   10001   9      1
```

The column order is not as you specified, but the shape and value are correct. I don't know of a way to move the columns around, but we can easily create a new dataframe with the right column ordering.

```
column_ordered = ['id', 'date', 'level', 'parent', 'category', 'name', 'value1', 'value2']
finaldf = pd.DataFrame()
for col in columns_ordered:
    finaldf[col] = dfnew[col]
```